# Sitecore User Group Sep 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are wicked excited to announce the Sep'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

Face Recognition and Personalization: Data-Driven Markteting In a Brick & Click Store by Rodrigo Peplau, Solution Architect at NishTech, Inc and 4x Sitecore Technology MVP (2016-current)

"Surprise Talk" by Una Verhoeven - Solution Architect and Founder at AmpleEdge | Sitecore MVP 2018-2019 | Member of SUGNL, SUGCON EU, Women of Sitecore.

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Sep, 11, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Sep, 11, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/264553826/) for more details and RSVP.